# Updating a Web Socket from Outside the Web Socket App

Tags: caching, websocket, socket.io

If I have an app (let's Express.js app) with a web socket (socket.io) and I want to send message to a client from a different server app, what is the best way to go about that.

Let's assume that both apps are on a public cloud and running on separate containers or VMs.  What's the best way to ensure that the message is sent to the right web socket app instance that holds the connection to the client?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [redis](https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/) to ensure that client will get the message no matter which instance of app is sending the message.

But if your other app is a completely different app and does not start a socket server, You can still use [socket.io emitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-emitter) (along with redis adaptor) to send messages to clients without creating another socket server.

Comment: in both examples, is there a way for the code holding the socket to be notified when a new message has to be routed to the client, versus having to poll redis?  I'm wondering how to make this more event driven.